# Convert 1D array to multiple 2D arrays in Java

Tags: multidimensional-array

I have a question.I have image pixel values which I stored in a 1D array. This array is large storing 64000 values.I want to create blocks of 8 x 8 2D array from these values. I am stuck and don't know where to begin.Could someone point me to the right direction?
If this approach is not ok, is there an alternative like storing pixel values in a large 2D array and dividing that into smaller blocks of 8 x8?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How can you define 64000 pixel values to 2D as 8*8 i.e. with 64 points/pixels?

Comment: I will have 1000 such blocks of 8 x 8 (64*1000=64000)

Comment: 3D array then? int[1000][8][8]?

Comment: I only need 2D array. I will perform DCT function on these arrays